# JavaFX FileChooser and DirectoryChooser: accessory component

Tags: java, javafx, filechooser

Swing's JFileChooser provides the [setAccessory](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#setAccessory%28javax.swing.JComponent%29) method to extend the file chooser by any Swing component, e.g. for a file preview or for the selection of options.

Is there any similar possibility in JavaFX's [FileChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html) and [DirectoryChooser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/DirectoryChooser.html)?

Comment: Did you found a solution?

Comment: No, I could not find a solution.

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59356411/javafx-embed-jfilechooser-using-swingnode-and-get-selected-file