# JavaFX embed JFileChooser using SwingNode and get selected file

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jfilechooser

I have integrated a JFileChooser into a JavaFX application using a [SwingNode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/embed/swing/SwingNode.html). The dialog displays and is usable, but I am unsure about how to get the selected file from it.

Thanks for any help.

```
@FXML
public void openDialog(MouseEvent event) {
    SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
        swingNode.setContent(fileChooser);
    });

    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    pane.setCenter(swingNode);

    Stage stage = new Stage();

    Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Why not use the [Java FX based `FileChooser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/stage/FileChooser.html)?

Comment: Unfortunately I am using a legacy library which was written in Swing. This is where the JFileChooser is coming from, so I have to use this.

Comment: Why not use `fileChooser.getSelectedFile`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of curiosity I made a small example to do this.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingNode;

import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class JunkFx extends Application {
    public void openDialog(MouseEvent event) {
        JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser("why");
        SwingNode swingNode = new SwingNode();

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            swingNode.setContent(fileChooser);
        });

        BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
        pane.setCenter(swingNode);

        Stage stage = new Stage();

        Scene scene = new Scene(pane, 500, 500);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        fileChooser.addActionListener(evt->{
            System.out.println(evt.getActionCommand());
            System.out.println(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
            Platform.runLater(stage::hide);
        });

    }


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Button b = new Button("click");
        b.setOnMouseClicked(this::openDialog);
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(b), 640, 480);
        stage.setTitle("open a dialog");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

There will be a response on the EDT, then you have to manage what to do with it, checking for cancelled or accepted etc. then fire an action onto the Platform thread.

Comment: like the filename :)

Comment: Bingo, that's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I wasn't familiar with Platform.runlater().